# get the id of an item that was stored in the database using bookshelf on node/express

Tags: node.js, express, bookshelf.js

Is there a way to know the id of my user that was stored in the database using bookshelf?

```
   const user= new User({
              name: array[i],
              login_trabajo_id: req.params.idTrabajo
          });

   user.save().then(() => {
               //...console.log(id);
           }).catch(err => {
                return res.send(err);
           });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try do it like this.

```
const user= new User({
  name: array[i],
  login_trabajo_id: req.params.idTrabajo
});

user.save().then((result) => {
  console.log(result.id); //console your saved id
  }).catch(err => {
    return res.send(err);
});
```

in my opinion best way to create apis by removing then and using try catch with async-await.

```
async function(req,res){

  const user= new User({
    name: array[i],
    login_trabajo_id: req.params.idTrabajo
  });

  try {
    let savedUser = await user.save()
    console.log('saved user id', savedUser.id)
  }
  catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error.message)
  }
}
```

*both the above codes work as same